# Regex match string or end of string

Tags: python, regex, lexer

I currently have this regex (with multiline and dotall flags):

```
^@@:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s*^(.*?)^@@
```

That matches this:

```
@@:variable

some nice MarkDown content blah blah

@@
```

I would like to be able to omit the closing @@ tag if the declaration is the last in the file (string), this is because many of the files will only have one declaration so the idea of closing it seems unnecessary. I tried this regex:

```
^@@:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s*^(.*?)^(@@|\A)
```

But it no longer even matches with the closing tag with that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you mean `(^@@|\A)`, or even `(^@@|\Z)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it now:

Two mistakes:

The caret had to be part of the first regex in the last group and I needed \Z not \A as \A matches start of string rather than end.

```
^@@:([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\s*^(.*?)(^@@|\Z)
```